# geom_ribbon doesn't work - Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ribbon

I try to add a `geom_ribbon` object to my `ggplot2` plot. In my data frame, I have `NA` values that (I guess) may cause a problem. This is a reproducible example of the data frame I have:

```
base <- c(1:10, rep(NA, 10))
output1 <- c(rep(NA, 9), 10 - 0:10)
output2 <- c(rep(NA, 9), 10 + 0:10)
xaxis <- 1:20

df <- data.frame(xaxis, base, output1, output2)
df

     xaxis base output1 output2
  1      1    1      NA      NA
  2      2    2      NA      NA
  3      3    3      NA      NA
  4      4    4      NA      NA
  5      5    5      NA      NA
  6      6    6      NA      NA
  7      7    7      NA      NA
  8      8    8      NA      NA
  9      9    9      NA      NA
  10    10   10      10      10
  11    11   NA       9      11
  12    12   NA       8      12
  13    13   NA       7      13
  14    14   NA       6      14
  15    15   NA       5      15
  16    16   NA       4      16
  17    17   NA       3      17
  18    18   NA       2      18
  19    19   NA       1      19
  20    20   NA       0      20
```

And my attempt to plot a `ggplot2` object with a `geom_ribbon`:

```
  dfm <- melt(df, id=1)
  ggplot(dfm, aes(x = xaxis, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group=variable)) + 
    geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(group = 1, ymin=output1, ymax=output2))
```

And, eventually, I got an **error I cannot deal with**:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You got this error because `variable` is used for color in `aes()` of function `ggplot()`. When you add `geom_ribbon()` with new data frame `geom_ribbon()` tries to find `variable` in new data frame to use it for colors. To ignore this variable add `inherit.aes=FALSE` inside `geom_ribbon()` - so you are telling that all parameters should be taken independently - that's way you should set `x=xaxis` again in `geom_ribbon()`.

```
ggplot(dfm, aes(x = xaxis, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=variable)) + 
  geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(group = 1, x = xaxis,ymin=output1, ymax=output2),
                       inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

Comment: Very useful, although a problem remains that the legend can get mixed up. See `d = data.frame(x = sample(-50:50,20), y = sample(-50:50,20), size = sample(1:10,20,rep=T));
rads = function(deg) return(pi * deg / 180);
poly = data.frame(x = 40*sin(rads(1:360)), y = 40*cos(rads(1:360)));
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, size=size)) + geom_point() + geom_polygon(data=poly, aes(x, y), fill=NA, col='black', inherit.aes=F)`

Comment: @geotheory Yes in this case it makes problem, but you can move `size=size` to `aes()` of `geom_point()` or set for example `size=1` in `geom_polygon()` (outside `aes()`)

Answer (score 2):

The definition for `color = variable` is being carried over from the original `ggplot` layer.
Override it in the call to `geom_ribbon` to make it work: `geom_ribbon(data = df, aes(group = 1, ymin=output1, ymax=output2, color=I('red'))`.