# in R: Error in is.data.frame(data) : object '' not found, C5.0 plot

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree

This question is similar to some other questions on Stackoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514482/error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object-not-found-with-xyplot), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891637/geom-ribbon-doesnt-work-error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object-variable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664585/error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-contradiction)), but different enough so that I cannot extrapolate those answers to my case.

I have a function in which I fit a C5.0 model and than try to plot the model.

```
train_d <- globald[train_ind,c(features,21)]
model <- C5.0(binclass ~ .,data=train_d,trials=10)
```

`binclass` is a column name in my training/test data (globald is a dataframe from which I subset rows with `_ind` indices and columns `c(3:12,21)`, where column 21 is named `binclass`). Fitting works well. However, when I also add the line

```
plot(model,trial=0)
```

then I get the following error: `Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'train_d' not found`.

How is it possible that when fitting the model, `train_d` is found and used correctly, but while plotting, `train_d` is nowhere to be found? And, any suggestion of how to solve this issue. Namespaces in [r] remain a mystery to me.

A minimal running example is the following:

```
f <- function(){
    library(C50)
    set.seed(1)
    class = c(1,2)
    d <- data.frame(feature1 = sample(1:10,10,replace=TRUE), feature2 = 1:10, binclass = class)
    d$binclass <- as.factor(d$binclass)
    model <- C5.0(binclass ~ ., data=d)
    plot(model)   
}
```

Calling `f()` results in the following error: `Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'd' not found`

Edit:
As per the answer from MrFlick, it seems that the cause of this problem is a bug in the C5.0 code. There are some workarounds are indicated by Pascal and MrFlick.

Comment: Which "other questions"? And without a reproducible example, it will be complicated to get an answer.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a namespace issue so much as a possible scope issue. However it's not very clear from the information you provided. You should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) making it clear exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @Pascal: a minimal working example is provided. I don't know if it's a namespace of a scope issue. It's an issue that I want to see resolved...

Comment: Not sure it is the best to do, but it works when you add `assign("d", d, .GlobalEnv)` after `d$binclass <- as.factor(d$binclass)`.

Comment: @Pascal. This seems a rather draconian measure. But hey, it works!

Comment: Yes, maybe better to wait for a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

There does appear to be a bug in the code when it comes to evaluating the command in the proper environment. The problem appears to be in the `C50::model.frame.C5.0` function. The "cleanest" work around I could find was to add a `terms` property to your model. This will help encapsulate the function environment.

```
f <- function(){
    library(C50)
    set.seed(1)
    class = c(1,2)
    d <- data.frame(feature1 = sample(1:10,10,replace=TRUE), feature2 = 1:10, binclass = class)
    d$binclass <- as.factor(d$binclass)
    model <- C5.0(binclass ~ ., data=d)
    model$terms <- eval(model$call$formula)   #<---- Added line
    plot(model)   
}
```

Comment: Ok. So it appears to be a bug in C5.0? The workaround do work though and at least mitigate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the special assignment operator <<- instead of the standard one (<-). It will save the object to the global environment and that can solve your problem.

Comment: love u @user10854911

Comment: This is why mine didn't work! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

@MrFlick almost had it but not quite. This problem for plotting is particularly annoying when trying to pass arbitrary data and target features to the C50 method. As pointed out by MrFlick it was to do with renaming terms. By renaming the x and y terms in the method call the plotting function won't get confused.

```
tree_model$call$x <- data_train[, -target_index]
tree_model$call$y <- data_train[[target_feature]]
```

For example, here is a method for passing in arbitrary data and a target feature and still being able to plot the result:

```
boosted_trees <- function(data_train, target_feature, iter_choice) {

    target_index <- grep(target_feature, colnames(data_train))
    model_boosted <- C5.0(x = data_train[, -target_index], y = data_train[[target_feature]], trial=iter_choice)
    model_boosted$call$x <- data_train[, -target_index]
    model_boosted$call$y <- data_train[[target_feature]]
    return(model_boosted)

}
```

The model object returned by the above method can be plotted as normal.

```
model <- boosted_trees(data_train, 'my_target', 10)
plot(model)
```